# How to get the updates after installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, system-installation, updates, offline

I'm having a bit of a problem, before I install Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop as dual boot, I thought of trying it before I jump into any unknown waters..

My problem is that I'm not able to install the recommended updates at the time of installation due to some problems I'm having with my Internet connection.

So what I would like to know is that, if there is a straight forward method of updating Ubuntu after installation, Or do I have to wait and make sure my internet connection is up before installing Ubuntu for it to be properly updated?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you don't have a working internet connection at installation time should not affect future updates in any way.

You will be prompted when you have a working connection and any updates are available.

You can also install updates manually by using the Software Center, or running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` in the terminal.